# Meteor: Where should we put common functions?

Tags: meteor

I have some common functions (E.g. trimInput(), isEmail(), isFacebookPage()...) in my project that I often use on client side. I was wondering where would it be **the best place** to put them so as to avoid code duplication?

```
trimInput = function(value) {
    return value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call them "helper" functions, not necessarily handlebars helpers.

This [unofficial FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) should give you an idea where to place what.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `server` and `client` folders, I usually create a `both` folder, containing all code that should be on both the client and the server. You basically get the same results as if you would name it `lib`, but putting common code in a folder named `lib` does not always make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you use these functions on both the server side and client side.

I would declare it has a helper function within a common.js file inside a /lib folder.